# Центрирование подменю bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Мне надо подменю отцентрировать в аккурат между ORANGE буквой а в логотипе и иконкой Пользователя
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
/* ============ desktop view ============ */

@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar .nav-item .dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar .nav-item:hover .nav-link {}
  .navbar .nav-item:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar .nav-item .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}


/* ============ desktop view .end// ============ */

body {
  background: #060707;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: #F5702C;
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #F5702C;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #999999;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-link:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

.wood {
  color: #999999;
}

.bi-search,
.bi-person,
.bi-cart3,
.bi-playstation {
  fill: #F5702C;
}

.bi-phone {
  fill: #999999;
}

.phone {
  color: #999999;
}

.dropdown-item img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  margin-right: -1000px;
}

.dropdown-menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/bootstrap.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/normalize.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="header-top">
      <div class="container fixed-top">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-playstation" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path d="M15.858 11.451c-.313.395-1.079.676-1.079.676l-5.696 2.046v-1.509l4.192-1.493c.476-.17.549-.412.162-.538-.386-.127-1.085-.09-1.56.08l-2.794.984v-1.566l.161-.054s.807-.286 1.942-.412c1.135-.125 2.525.017 3.616.43 1.23.39 1.368.962 1.056 1.356ZM9.625 8.883v-3.86c0-.453-.083-.87-.508-.988-.326-.105-.528.198-.528.65v9.664l-2.606-.827V2c1.108.206 2.722.692 3.59.985 2.207.757 2.955 1.7 2.955 3.825 0 2.071-1.278 2.856-2.903 2.072Zm-8.424 3.625C-.061 12.15-.271 11.41.304 10.984c.532-.394 1.436-.69 1.436-.69l3.737-1.33v1.515l-2.69.963c-.474.17-.547.411-.161.538.386.126 1.085.09 1.56-.08l1.29-.469v1.356l-.257.043a8.454 8.454 0 0 1-4.018-.323Z" class="bi-playstation"/>
            </svg> &nbsp;ORANGE
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Переключатель навигации">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
            <div class="wood">Разработано в Германии. Сделанов в России.</div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
              <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 hide">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">О компании</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">О продукции</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    Каталог товаров
                </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="https://bootstraptema.ru/snippets/icons/2016/mia/1.png"><span>Смесители</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="https://bootstraptema.ru/snippets/icons/2016/mia/1.png"><span>Мебель</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="https://bootstraptema.ru/snippets/icons/2016/mia/1.png"><span>Душевая программа</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="https://bootstraptema.ru/snippets/icons/2016/mia/1.png"><span>Фаянс</span></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>

              <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
                <ul class="nav ">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link phone" href="tel:+78005108080">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-phone" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                          <path d="M11 1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h6zM5 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H5z"/>
                          <path d="M8 14a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2z" class="bi-phone"/>
                        </svg> +7 (800) 510-80-80</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item hide">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cart3" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                          <path d="M0 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 1H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 3H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .49.598l-1 5a.5.5 0 0 1-.465.401l-9.397.472L4.415 11H13a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.491-.408L2.01 3.607 1.61 2H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3.102 4l.84 4.479 9.144-.459L13.89 4H3.102zM5 12a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm7 0a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm-7 1a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z" class="bi-cart3"/>
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item hide">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                          <path d="M8 8a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm2-3a2 2 0 1 1-4 0 2 2 0 0 1 4 0zm4 8c0 1-1 1-1 1H3s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4zm-1-.004c-.001-.246-.154-.986-.832-1.664C11.516 10.68 10.289 10 8 10c-2.29 0-3.516.68-4.168 1.332-.678.678-.83 1.418-.832 1.664h10z" class="bi-person"/>
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z" class="bi-search"/>
                          </svg>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <section class="rororo mt-5">
    <h5>One section</h5>
  </section>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <section class="rororo mt-2">
    <h5>Two section</h5>
  </section>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <section class="rororo mt-2">
    <h5>Three section</h5>
  </section>

  <script src="asset/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>

  <script src="asset/js/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>

  <script src="asset/js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```